# How to specify multiple .pws and .prepl files in ASPELL_CONF?

Tags: aspell

I'm trying to configure aspell version 3.1.20 to use the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/` directory instead of `~/.aspell`. According the the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory), one can do so by setting the `ASPELL_CONF` environment variable to something like

```bsh
"per-conf $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/aspell.conf; personal $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/en.pws; repl $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/en.prepl"
```

However, I'm Brazilian and I regurlarly use aspell to check spelling in both English and Portuguese. In other words, I need to specify multiple `.pws` and `.prepl` files (one for each language). I tried doing something along the lines of

```bsh
export ASPELL_CONF="per-conf $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/aspell.conf; personal $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/en.pws; repl $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/en.prepl $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/pt_BR.pws; repl $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/pt_BR.prepl"
```

but I'm getting the following error messages:

```
$ aspell -l pt_BR check doc.txt
Error: Expected language "pt_BR" but got "en".

$ aspell -l en check doc.txt
Error: Expected language "pt_BR" but got "en".
```

How do I specify `.pws` and `.prepl` files for multiple languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. I think, I was able to solve this by moving all my `.aspell*` files into `~/.config/aspell/` and specifying

```bsh
export ASPELL_CONF="home-dir $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/aspell/"
```

I am not sure, why does the Arch Wiki suggests specifying the path to every file separately. Maybe there is some edge case that I am not aware of, but for me the above approach worked flawlessly.

Comment: This is working flawlessly for me too. Thanks!